# ssh for loop and IFS

Tags: bash, loops, shell, ifs

Despite my searches, I can't find what's wrong.

Locally :

```
RESULT="dir 1
dir 2"
IFS=$'\n'
for R in $RESULT ; do
    echo "$R"
done
```

is ok

Remotely :

```
RESULT="dir 1
dir 2"
ssh -x -T ${HOST}<<-EOF
IFS=$'\n'
for R in $RESULT ; do
    echo "\$R"
done
EOF
```

gives error:

```
-bash: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `dir'
-bash: line 4: `dir 2 ; do'
```

My need is obviously not that simple, but it seems to me that this is the simplest example that corresponds to it.

Edit:
Thanks for the answers, but I can't get the desired result with declare -p RESULT, even after consulting all the links indicated

```
$ for i in ${RESULT[@]} ; do echo "$i" ; done
dir 1
dir 2
$ ssh -x -T ${POSTE_DEST}<<-EOF
$(declare -p RESULT)
for R in ${RESULT[@]} ; do
echo "\$R"
done
EOF
dir
1
dir
2
```

Maybe you could give me a real answer that works?

For @Barmar:

```
ssh -x -T ${POSTE_DEST}<<-EOF
> $(declare -p RESULT)
> for R in "${RESULT[@]}" ; do
> echo "\$R"
> done
> EOF
dir 1 dir 2
```

Comment: `$RESULT` is being expanded on the local machine, setting `IFS` on the remote machine has no effect.

Comment: `$(declare -p RESULT)` expands to code that, if evaluated by the remote shell, will expand to the original value. If you move your code into a function, you can do the same trick with `$(declare -f funcname)` to serialize that function. We have existing Q&A describing this.

Comment: Instead of using a variable, put `RESULT` in a file. Copy the file to the remote machine, then send commands to read from the file.

Comment: In the answer to the linked duplicate, see the section _Generating an eval-safe command dynamically: Function Edition_. (Doing that with `declare -p` to pass the variables the function depends on will also let you avoid the hackery with `IFS` altogether and use a real array instead).

Comment: ...I added a second linked duplicate _directly_ on-point for passing arrays over ssh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't do it

Comment: @barmar using a file is not a solution for that

Comment: @Chris972, please show how you tried; can't say why it failed if we don't see the attempt.

Comment: Ah. You only followed half my advice, and ignored the `declare -f` part (despite it being explicitly present in the link you claim to have thoroughly consulted).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/ab6c66be9fe994b885bacabf5c45f7fb -- using `declare -f` ensures that you're getting the function represented _exactly_ as it's locally defined, without any unwanted expansions taking place as your code is being interpreted before runtime by the remote shell.

Comment: `for R in ${RESULT[@]}` you're missing the quotes: `for R in "${RESULT[@]}"`

Comment: @barmar No ! with quotes, I'll have ALL in one line `dir 1 dir 2` That's not what I need at all.

Comment: @Chris972, barmar is correct; the quotes ensure that content keeps its original boundaries; _leaving them out_ is what blurs them.

Comment: No it won't. `bash` understands `[@]` inside quotes to mean that it should expand the array and then re-quote each element.

Comment: @Chris972, mind, `"${RESULT[*]}"` would expand all the elements into just one string, but there's a reason we're specifying `[@]` instead of `[*]`.

Comment: The solution is way too cumbersome, because, like I said, it's just a simplified example of my need. I need to treat these results remotely, otherwise it doesn't make sense. I'm going to see how to do it differently. The solution of exporting array and function is not at all interesting.

Comment: (btw, re: variable name capitalization, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and other POSIX-defined tools, whereas other names are reserved for "application use"; this applies even to regular shell variables, since setting one overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Comment: Why do you think the code given _isn't_ "treat[ing] these results remotely"?

Comment: As for the "for barmar" example you edited in, it's only because you're expanding _into a heredoc_ that you have that problem. Serialize the code via a function and it'd disappear.

Comment: If barmar is correct, why do you make me use a remote function to do the work ? I don't understand anything of what you both mean.
I just want to remotely loop on my local values. Just that.

Comment: `${array[@]}` acts identical to `${array[*]}` when the expansion is taking place in a context that only permits a single string; a heredoc is such a context. By contrast, when the function is remotely defined and being executed, `"${array[@]}"` is parsed in the context of `for i in`, where an array is perfectly valid and will expand into individual words.

Comment: Have you actually _tried following_ the advice you're being given? If you tried it, and had a problem, that would be a much less frustrating situation than you reporting back to us problems that you encounter _only because you refuse to follow directions_ as if it were a fault in the directions you aren't following.

Comment: (That said -- which version of bash are you running? If the local system will always be on bash 5.0 or later, there's an alternate approach I hate to advise, because it's comparatively error-prone, but that doesn't require any techniques you've as yet refused to use).

Comment: From the perspective of understanding _why_ there's a problem, and why function-wrapping fixes it, by the way -- try replacing your ssh command with `cat`. That is to say, change `ssh -x -T ${POSTE_DEST}<<-EOF` to `cat <<-EOF` and read the code that's printed. Most immediately, you'll see `"${RESULT[@]}"` is expanded _before_ `cat` or `ssh` is run, so the definition that `declare -p` creates is ignored; whereas if you move the reference to `"${RESULT[@]}"` into a function, its expansion is deferred until the function is called without needing to manually add backslashes throughout your code.

Comment: That "without needing to manually add backslashes" isn't just an ease-of-maintenance concern -- it's also about correctness and security. When you expand a variable into a context where it's parsed as code, then you need to worry about what happens on the remote machine if, say, your variable happens to contain `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`. By contrast, if you use `declare -p` or a similar construct to generate an eval-safe escaping of your data, it's going to come back out of the shell parser exactly identical to how it went in.

Comment: (well, move the reference into a function _that's serialized with `declare -f`_; if you just define the function manually in the heredoc it still needs to be backslash-escaped and the problem isn't fixed; it's really the `declare -f` that's the solution, and the function is incidental necessity).